# Why isn't fs loading my index.html file in my node.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using fs to load an index.html from my index.js file, but not only is it not loading, but the testing I put inside the fs function call isn't being logged either.

Here is my entire index.js file:

```
const cron = require("cron");
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
    console.log("inside readFileSync, before error handling");
    if (err) {
        console.log("inside readFileSync, in error handling");
        throw err; 
    }
    console.log("inside readFileSync, past error handling");
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(8000);
});

// init global config
global.config = require("../src/util/config");

const MatchingBot = require("../src/MatchingBot");

var time = new Date();
console.log(time.getHours()+":"+time.getMinutes()+"________________");

new cron.CronJob({
  cronTime: config.CRON_TIME,
  onTick: MatchingBot.run,
  start: true
});
```

Here are my logs:

```
> matching-bot@1.0.0 start /var/app/current
> node ./bin/index.js | bunyan

17:44________________
inside readFileSync, before error handling
inside readFileSync, past error handling
```

When I navigate to my app, I get a 502 bad gateway error.

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

**EDIT:** I updated the function from `readFileSync` to `readFile`, and I see my logs now, no error is thrown, but still when I navigate to my application I see a `502 Bad Gateway` error.

Comment: Can you show the actual run log? (on a syntax note, why mix `const` and `var`? you won't be modifying `http`, `fs`, or `time, so marking those `const` makes a lot of sense)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I changed those to const as well.  I updated that and the function call and am now seeing my logs, but still the index.html isn't rendering.

Comment: Your post isn't showing your actual logs, though, so please still add those. With that said, 502 bad gateway is not caused by Node: the error accurately describes the problem (whatever gateway/proxy is between "you" and "node" has not been configured correctly, so you may not have aeb configured to properly route your calls)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I added the logs. That is a good point, I will try troubleshooting it more from that perspective.

Comment: For debugging purposes you probably also want to do is change `http.createServer(...).listen(8000)` to ```const server = http.createServer(...); server.listen(8000, () => { console.log(`server listening on ${server.address()}`)```

Answer (score 0):

Well you're calling the *wrong* method. (considering what you're trying to do)

`readFileSync` does **not** take a callback.

> fs.readFileSync(path[, options])

You probably want `readFile` method

> fs.readFile(path[, options], callback)

Comment: Thank you, I updated it so we're calling readFile. I'm seeing my logs now but still getting a 502 gateway error.

Comment: server works on my local. `localhost:8000`. Maybe you need to straighten out some other configuration